# Uniform distribution that depends on exponential?

Tags: statistics, random-variables, uniform-distribution, exponential-distribution

So I'm trying to solve this problem:

Let $X \sim \operatorname{Exponential}(\lambda)$. Let $Y \sim \operatorname{Uniform}(0,X)$. You are given $\operatorname{E}[X] = 1/ \lambda$ and $\operatorname{E}[X^2] = 2/\lambda^2$.

What are $\operatorname{E}[Y]$ and $\operatorname{Var}[Y]$?

So my initial thought was just to use the formula $\operatorname{E}[X] = \frac{1}{2}(a+b)$ for the expectation of a uniform variable and use $\operatorname{E}[X] = 1/ \lambda$ as $b$ for the above formula.

This is obviously wrong.

My next approach was to just think of this as a joint distribution as follows:

$$
f_{XY}=\frac{1}{\lambda \exp(-\lambda x) }
$$

I got this by using the pdf formula for uniform distribution: $f(x) = \frac{1}{b-a}$
and the formula for pdf of exponetial: $f(x) = \lambda \exp(-\lambda x)$.

Next step would be to find the marginal distribution of $Y$ using:

$$
f_Y= \int_x\frac{1}{\lambda \exp(-\lambda x) }
$$

Once I have the marginal distribution I can find the expectation and variance.
But this integral is just infinity if I'm doing it right.

What am I doing wrong? Is there an issue with how I'm conceptually framing this problem?

Comment: Alternatively, try using the Law of Total Expectation: $\mathbb{E}(Y) = \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(Y|X))$.

Comment: Could you possibly expand on this a little? I'm not familiar with the law of total expectation and the wiki page is pretty verbose.

Comment: Literally, just apply the formula in the comment. You can hardly complain about the verbosity of the comment; it's only half a line of text.

Comment: Do you know what $E(Y|X)$ is? How about $E(Y|X=x)?$// For $\lambda = 2,$ I get $E(Y) = 1/4$ and for $\lambda=3$ it's $E(Y) = 1/6.$